# Parsing a pwdump file python

Tags: python, string, split

I'm trying to parse a pwdump file in python.
The content of a pwdump file looks like this:

```
...[snip]

Domain\TESTIN$::aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee:31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0:::

Guest(current):501:aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee:31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0:::

Guest(hist_01):501:aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee:31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0:::

Guest(hist_02):501:aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee:31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0:::

...[snip]
```

I would like to get 2 things out of this:

```
Domain\USER (So first string before the ":")
```

And the actual hash :

```
"aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee:31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0"
```

I was thinking about something like this :

```
import sys

infile, outfile = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]

with open(infile) as inf, open(outfile,"w") as outf:
    line_words = (line.split('::') for line in inf)
    outf.writelines(words[1].strip() + '\n' for words in line_words if len(words)>1)
```

But somehow I have only the first hash parsed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're splitting on `"::"`. Try splitting on `":"` instead. Only the first line conforms to this format. Lines 2 and up have a number between two `:`s, which mucks with your algorithm.

Try this instead (more verbose for readability):

```
with open(infile) as inf, open(outfile,"w") as outf:
    for line in inf:
        splits = line.split(":")
        user, hash = splits[0], ":".join(splits[2:4])
        outf.write(hash + '\n')
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Yep, but i only get one part of the hash as a result : "00000000000000000000000000000000" while I'm looking for the complete hash. Maybe the best would be to use regex instead ?

Comment: Sorry I meant; 
 
Yep, but i only get one part of the hash as a result : "aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee" while I'm looking for the complete hash. Maybe the best would be to use regex instead ?

Also, I dont get the other lines somehow :/

Comment: Thanks for your update, now I can get the first hash. I'm not really sure why, but it only does the first line, not the others, which is weird :(

Comment: I checked my algorithm against the snippet that you provided, and it gets both hashes of every line. Either I'm missing your question or your snippet is inconsistent with your data

Comment: No you're right :) Actually Pwdump add a ^M character at the end of each line. Python dont see a new line...

Comment: Ahh! In that case, may I suggest a `tr` as a preprocessing step?

Comment: @user1473508: you could try  `open(infile, "rU")` to handle unusual newlines

Comment: `line.partition(':')` allows to avoid the join

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: how is the '\n' unnecessary? Is it perhaps because you are on a version of python that adds it for you directly?

Comment: iterating over a file doesn't remove trailing newline characters from the lines

Comment: Yes, but splitting on `":"` means that the pieces that contain the hash will not have a trailing '\n'

Comment: you're right. I haven't noticed `:::` at the end (it is cutoff on iPad).